# jQuery add a row in a table with increment order

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a `table`. Inside that there is a `single row for form input elements`. I have put a `button` named as `add line` just `below that table`. When a user `clicks on the button add line` it will `add another row in that table`. But here I need that when a user will click on the button add line it will `add another row with increment id`. Suppose now I have the `row_1 id is visible`. When the user will click on the `add line button` it will show another row but the `newly added row's id will be row_2`. Here is the code that I have done yet

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-IN">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.7.2.js"></script>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("#add-line").click(function() {
        var row = jQuery('.prototype tr').clone(true);
        row.find("input:text").val("");
        row.appendTo('.form-fields table');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
  <div id="form">
  <table id="form-headings">
    <tr>
      <td width="15%">Id</td>
      <td width="16%">Name</td>
      <td width="13%">Col3</td>
      <td width="14%">Col4</td>
      <td width="12%">Col5</td>
    </tr>
  </table><!--table#form-headings-->
  <div id="row_1">
  <div class="form-fields">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_id" size="5px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_name" size="5px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_col3" size="5px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_col4" size="5px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_col5" size="5px"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div><!--.form-fields-->
  </div><!--#row_01-->
  <input type="button" id="add-line" value="Add Line" />
  </div><!--#form-->
  <table class="prototype" style="display:none">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="form_id" size="5px"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="form_name" size="5px"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="form_col3" size="5px"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="form_col4" size="5px"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="form_col5" size="5px"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table><!--table.prototype-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: row_1 id is the id for the div. then how can you create for row

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this if you want to add the id for the row means example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/mH3en/2/)

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var id = 0;
      jQuery("#add-line").click(function() {
        id++;           
        var row = jQuery('.prototype tr').clone(true);
        row.find("input:text").val("");
        row.attr('id',id); 
        row.appendTo('.form-fields table');        
        return false;
    });

    jQuery('.form-fields .remove').live('click', function() {
         jQuery(this).parents("tr").remove();              
    });    
});
```

if you want to have different id for the form element means you have to create a new element don't use clone

Comment: thanks for the answer. It worked but I want to know what to do when there will be no row present at all and I will click on add line button then it will not add new row as because of `var last_id = jQuery('.form-fields table tr:last').attr('id')` and there is no row is present. So how to solve this?

Comment: If you want to delete functinality also means try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/mH3en/2/

Answer (score 0):

`id` must be unique, also I think your example could be more shorter, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DKWnE/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var template = $('#template'),
        id = 0;

    $("#add-line").click(function() {
        var row = template.clone();
        template.find("input:text").val("");
        row.attr('id', 'row_' + (++id));
        row.find('.remove').show();
        template.before(row);
    });

    $('.form-fields').on('click', '.remove', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you. It worked finally. But in case of remove the lines I added a button called remove-row and then I used         `jQuery('#remove-row').live('click', function(event) {
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
`.
It is removing the fields but when all the rows has gone empty and again I am clicking on add line it's not adding more row.So how to solve that

Comment: @webdeveloper.Thank you for the reply.But I want remove button should be there in every row and when click on remove even last row should be delete at last and when click on add line it should make a new row.That I want.No need to use the css for remove `display:none`.